# Hp Pavilion G6 doesn't turn on. Pressing the on button starts, but goes off automatically

Tags: hp-pavilion

Here is the full story.
My Hp Pavilion G6 2110sx it's not turning on after not using for 3 days

When I press the power on button it turns on and then goes off immediately. When I pressed the button again, it did not react. So I left it for a while without touching it.

After that when I pressed again the power on button, it turned on and went off like the first instance.

I opened it and performed some checks.

```
Power cord is fully working
The DC jack is also working 
Power button does not have a problem
I tried to use it without battery and also the hard reset but nothing happened.
```

I don't know what the problem is. Help me to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem looks to be associated with your Motherboard on your laptop. Unfortunately, there is not much that can be done in order to fix this. It sounds like power is not traveling through the board and allowing your system to power on.

What you can try to do is remove your battery and disconnect the AC charger and hold the power button for about 5-10 seconds. Then, release the power button and plug in your AC adapter. Then try to power on the system. What this will do is discharge the capacitors which can sometimes be causing this problem.

If this does not work, it looks like your motherboard is no longer functioning and will have to be replaced. If it is still under [warranty](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/weInput?cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&product=5282061), or if you have an HP store near you, you can bring it there and allow them to give you a quote for how much it will cost to fix. However, from past experience, this isn't very cheap and it is usually better to start looking at another laptop.

Comment: I did that hard reset .this time too it starts on and then goes off

Comment: Do you think it is a problem with the dc jack .???because changing motherboard is like changing a new laptop.

Comment: It sounds more like the power-supply or motherboard itself. The problem is that would have to replace the board in order to fix either of those problems :(

Comment: doubt it would be a power jack problem if the computer turns on consistantly for a split second

Comment: have you tried resetting the cmos battery?